# Unity profiler spikes with vsync vs smooth no vsync

Tags: unity, vsync, profiler

I'm trying to profile my game, this is a webgl game, and the browser forces vsync.

My problem is, when I disable vsync in unity I get a pretty smooth profiler, while with vsync I get huge spikes.

I cant tell if this is an editor issue or this spikes exist in the webgl version as well (I do have stuttering when playing in the browser, but cant tell if these spikes are the same ones)

I don't display the WaitForTargetFPS in profiler as it is not interesing.

no vsync:
[image]

with vsync:
[image]

Any ideas friends?

Comment: Which methods take significantly longer in the spike samples than on other frames?